# Statistics data treatment with Symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, statistics

I use Symfony2 for a bill manager tool.
My customers would like to have many statistics about their bills : how much they spent month per month ; per providers ; etc...

My database (MySQL) is pretty huge and creating the statistic "on the fly" is pretty eager. So I'm trying to find a better solution to generate the statistics.

I'm considering 2 solutions :

1. Create a table dedicated to the statistics
2. Use a SQL view to have a first data-treatment step before the PHP script. But Doctrine2 doesn't handle SQL views...

Do you have any piece of advice for my case ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Did you see this post ? You can handle views with doctrine 2 
http://www.doctrine-project.org/2009/06/19/using-views-with-doctrine.html

Answer (score 0):

You should define an optimisation plan:

- Good starting point is to optimize mysql queries: [MySQL Optimisation Chapter](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/optimization.html)
- Also you could take in consideration the possibility to partially use Doctrine, it have slow performance on big datasets, `PDO` recommended. Use `PDO` for selects and `Doctrine` For data validation, inserts/updates.